# Configuração do NGINX + uWSGI + Django em uma aplicação multi-tenancy

Tags: django, amazon-aws, nginx, multi-tenancy

Eu tenho uma single application em django hospedada na AWS. Mas, esses dias, eu a transformei em multi-tenancy, usando django-tenant-schemas. Localmente, ela roda normalmente. Eu consigo criar meus tenants e acessá-los no meu servidor django local. No entanto, eu não sei como fazer rodar na AWS.

Meu arquivo .conf para o NGINX está assim:

```bsh
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/ubuntu/pasta_meu_projeto/mysite.sock; # for a file s$
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen      80; address or $
    server_name ssh *.example.com.br;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/pasta_meu_projeto/media;  # your Django project's$
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/pasta_meu_projeto/static; # your Django project's$
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/pasta_meu_projeto/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi$
    }
}
```

Fiz pull para o meu projeto que roda na AWS, tudo funcionou. E minha única alteração para acessar os subdomínios (apenas o que eu mudei) foi no arquivo acima, colando o * antes do ponto: `*.example.com.br`. Tentei usar regex também, mas também não deu muito certo (`server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.example\.com\.br$;`). Alguém sabe dizer o que eu devo fazer? Quais são as configurações do nginx? Se além de mexer no **.conf**, devo fazer alguma outra configuração, em algum outro "lugar"?

Comment: Qual servidor wsgi vc esta usando? qual é a sua duvida?

Comment: Oi, @Sidon! Obrigado por responder! Eu estou usando **uWSGI**. Eu quero saber se há algo faltando nesse meu **.conf** e se preciso fazer alguma configuração a mais, além do que eu já fiz.

Comment: Tem algum motivo especial para voce não usar o que é quase um padrão no mundo django? [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) Qual problema vc esta tendo? Sua pergunta nao está clara, veja que já foi até negativada.

Comment: Não, eu não tenho nenhum motivo espcial. Os dois são equivalentemente bons! Apenas resolvi usar o uWSGI. Vou tentar ser mais claro...

Comment: Acho muito dificil dizer que qq sw é melhor do que outro,  nesse caso então seria mais dificil ainda pq não conheco o uWSGI, mas se me pedisse uma recomendação eu recomendaria o Gunicorn, pelo motivo de ser muito mais difundido no mundo django, [veja essa comparação](https://stackshare.io/stackups/gunicorn-vs-uwsgi)

Comment: Quando eu crio o subdomínio localmente, por exemplo, **prefixo.localhost**, consigo acessar a aplicação: http://prefixo.localhost, na porta 8000. Eu gostaria, da mesma forma, de acessar prefixo.exemplo.com.br nessa minha VPN. Das minhas configurações iniciais, a única coisa que eu mudei foi essa linha citada (**server_name *.example.com.br**). Ao acessar, o subdomínio criado, não me retorna nada, apesar de perceber que meu NGINX está rodando por meio daquela mensagem clássica (Welcome to nginx!), tentando acessar o domínio sem prefixo, **http://exemplo.com.br**.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104762/discussion-between-sidon-and-thales).

Comment: Tudo bem, essa não é minha dúvida. Então, por favor, se você puder me dizer os passos que devo seguir para transformar minha single app em uma multi, usando o Gunicorn, eu realmente agradeço. Acredito que as mudanças das configurações do meu ngnix não vão afetar minha aplicação, até porque quem está na porta é o meu NGINX e não quem conversa com o Django.

Comment: Te mandei  o link para a solução de multsite no nginx+gunicorn no chat, tente primeiro e, se algo sair errado, reformule a pergunta ou faça outra.
Em tempo... Sua pergunta continua obscura e candidata a fechamento.

Comment: Pessoal da UP se puder para ajudar essa resposta subir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta para minha questão foi simples e dada de forma direta quando postada no Stackoverflow em Inglês. Para muitos, parece que minha questão foi rasa. No entanto, gostaria de resumir mais uma vez qual era a minha dúvida. Eu gostaria de saber o que deveria configurar no meu .conf do Nginx para poder acessar meus tenants, subdomínios. A resposta veio de forma direta, sem questionamentos:

- Trocar `server_name ssh *.example.com.br;`

**POR**

- `server_name ssh.example.com.br *.example.com.br;`
- Por fim, Acrescentar para cada subdomínio:

```bsh
server {
  server_name subdmino1.example.com.br;
  # ...
}

server {
  server_name subdominio2.example.com.br;
  # ...
}


server {
  server_name subdominio3.example.com.br;
  # ...
}
```

Desse modo, com a ajuda do @Jean-Jacques MOIROUX, [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342932/configuring-nginx-uwsgi-django-in-a-multi-tenancy-application), e este [tutorial](https://hackprogramming.com/how-to-setup-subdomain-or-host-multiple-domains-using-nginx-in-linux-server/), resolvi meu problema em pouco mais de 5 min. Abaixo seguem as configurações para o meu arquivo:

```bsh
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/ubuntu//mysite.sock; # for a file s$
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen      80;
    # Linha acrescentada do tutorial
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name ssh.example.com.br *.example.com.br;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/pasta_meu_projeto/media;  # your Django project's$
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/pasta_meu_projeto/static; # your Django project's$
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/pasta_meu_projeto/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi$
    }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    # Linha acrescentada do tutorial
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name subdominio1.example.com.brr;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/pasta_meu_projeto/media;  # your Django project's$
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/pasta_meu_projeto/static; # your Django project's$
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/pasta_meu_projeto/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi$
    }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    # Linha acrescentada do tutorial
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name subdominio2.example.com.br;
    # mesmas configurações acima
}
```